# many to many relationship in Windows Phone database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, windows-phone

I've been rummaging in the web but found no solution to speed up creation of my database on WindowsPhone emulator. And my question: Is there a way to speed up following many to many relationship? In order to create the database I have to add a List of `SimilarCollection` for every `Word` and into each of it I have to add few `WordJunctionSimilar` which should store the reference to some Word. It is frustrating and really complex. Is there a better solution?

(Only `SimilarCollection` and `WordJunctionSimilar` code is important)

```
[Table]
public class Word
{
    [Table]
    public class SimilarCollection
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int SimilarId { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Translation { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public int? WordId { get; set; }
        private EntitySet<WordJunctionSimilar> junction;
        [Association(Name = "FK_Similar_Words1", Storage = "junction", ThisKey = "SimilarId", OtherKey = "SimilarId")]
        public EntitySet<WordJunctionSimilar> Junction
        {
            get { return junction; }
            set { junction = value; }
        }
        public SimilarCollection()
        {
            Junction = new EntitySet<WordJunctionSimilar>((w) => w.SimilarId = this.SimilarId,(w) => w.SimilarId = 0);
        }

    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int WordId { get; set; }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Foreign { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Conjugation { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string SpeechPart { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    private EntitySet<SimilarCollection> similar;
    [Association(Name = "FK_Words_Similar", ThisKey = "WordId", OtherKey = "WordId", Storage = "similar")]
    public EntitySet<SimilarCollection> Similar
    {
        get { return similar; }
        set { similar = value; }
    }
    public Word()
    {
        Conjugation = "";
        SpeechPart = "";
        Type = "";
        Similar = new EntitySet<SimilarCollection>(OnSimilarAdded,OnSimilarRemoved);
    }
    private void OnSimilarAdded(SimilarCollection similar)
    {
        similar.WordId = this.WordId;
    }
    private void OnSimilarRemoved(SimilarCollection similar)
    {
        similar.WordId = null;
    }
}

[Table]
public class WordJunctionSimilar
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public int  WordId;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public int SimilarId;

    private EntityRef<Word> wordRef;
    [Association(Name="FK_Similar_Words0", Storage="wordRef",ThisKey="WordId",OtherKey="WordId")]
    public Word WordRef
    {
        get { return wordRef.Entity; }
        set { wordRef.Entity = value; WordId = value.WordId;  }
    }

    public WordJunctionSimilar()
    {
        wordRef = new EntityRef<Word>();
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't got a nested class `SimilarCollection`, have you?

Comment: Yes, I have, Is something wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know. I'm surprised it works is all. Logically I don't see a reason to nest a _public_ class that has associations outside its container class too. But it's a bit off topic.

Comment: I had done it before I got to know that Entity Framework can't handle storing list of objects, and I didn't feel like changing it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to speed up the DB creation - don't create the DB. Instead, distribute the complete .SDF file: in your XAP, and/or in GZip archive downloadable from the web.

Usually, WP7 hardware devices work much slower compared to the simulator. If your database is *that* slow on the simulator, it could be completely unusable on physical device.

I'd like to add that a relational database (such as SQLCE) is not a silver bullet: sometimes, other data structures could be more performant, even by several orders of magnitude. This applied to both in-memory data, and storage formats.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved issue by simply running "database creator" in second thread (non UI) and it boosted up from 19 hour to few seconds ;D